# Python Socket Function Error , can't find socket.gethostbyname

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I was coding a small program to monitor my Websites and if they are still online.

I tried following on my Windows-Computer in Visual Studio Code and it worked:

```
import socket
hostName = "example.org"
ipAddress = socket.gethostbyname(hostName)
print(ipAddress)
```

But I want to run this on an Ubuntu-System, so I transferred it to Ubuntu. But here I always get the following Compiling-Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
import socket

File "/root/Music/socket.py", line 3, in <module>
ipAddress = socket.gethostbyname(hostName)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'
```

Is there anything I forgot? Sorry, I'm new to this, so I would be thankful for every help.

I checked, but the sockets-library is up to date:

```
pip3 install sockets
Requirement already satisfied: sockets in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.0.0)
```

I also uninstall and installed sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File "/root/Music/socket.py"` seems not to be the standard socket module that you want, just appearing first in the module search path. You should remove the files `socket.py` and `socket.pyc` from `/root/Music`.